# Converting MSSQL to MySQL - Struggling with stored procedures

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

When trying to convert MSSQL to MySQL, I'm having some trouble converting stored procedures. I have used the migration wizard via the MySQL workbench but a lot hasn't been properly converted so I'm having to do it manually. I'm getting a syntax error when running a query (Error Code 1064) but I can't tell what's wrong with it.

```
INSERT INTO tblAuditInfo

        (`ActionOwner`

        ,`ActionDate`

        ,`PropertyID`

        ,`UsernameModified`

        ,`FieldModified`

        ,`OldValue`

        ,`NewValue`)

  VALUES

         ('ADMIN',NOW(),5,@Username,'I @Id',NULL,'Deleted')         



SELECT @PlanID



 END;
```

I've spent quite some time looking through other stackoverflow posts and reading through manuals but haven't been able to find anything related. Any help would be much appreciated.

The line it says the error was on was SELECT @PlanID

Comment: That snippet we do have isn't an SP; it's just an `INSERT` statement followed by a `SELECT`.

Comment: OP is moving to MySQL *from* SQL Server, @SeanLange , not the other way round.

Comment: @Larnu derp...helps if I read the question.

Comment: Unlike MSSQL MYSQL statements have to be terminated - your insert isn't.

Comment: To add to the comment above me; without seeing the rest of the proc, your use of @variables is suspect. Local variables and parameters in MYSQL do not use `@`, `@` is used for "session" variables (that are global to the session/connection) in MySQL.